# What does the on-boarding process of an Office 365 user look like?

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365

I'm trying to document the general steps that are part of the on-boarding proces of an Office 365 user. This is what I have so far:

On-boarding an Office 365 user

- Setup account and mailbox
- Assign licenses to user in Office 365

(-  Add user to the correct teams in Microsoft Teams)

Now I'm wondering if the process is really this simple, or if I'm missing some steps? If anybody knows an important step in the on-boarding process of an Office 365 user - that I didn't mention - then please help me out! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have already mentioned the two most basic steps.

Besides, you may be interested in [Help your employee get started](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/add-users/add-new-employee?view=o365-worldwide#step-4-help-your-employee-get-started) and [Assign admin roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/add-users/assign-admin-roles?view=o365-worldwide#assign-admin-roles-1).